# Object of type 'UnityEngine.Object' cannot be converted to type 'UnityEngine.Transform'

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm trying to make an option menu, but I've encountered the error stated on the title, I haven't used any code.

[image: Image1]

[image: Image2]

Edit: Full image of the editor and error code.

[image: image editor]

Error code:

> ArgumentException: Object of type 'UnityEngine.Object' cannot be
> converted to type 'UnityEngine.Transform'.
> System.RuntimeType.CheckValue (System.Object value,
> System.Reflection.Binder binder, System.Globalization.CultureInfo
> culture, System.Reflection.BindingFlags invokeAttr) (at
> :0)
> System.Reflection.MonoMethod.ConvertValues (System.Reflection.Binder
> binder, System.Object[] args, System.Reflection.ParameterInfo[] pinfo,
> System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture,
> System.Reflection.BindingFlags invokeAttr) (at
> :0)
> System.Reflection.MonoCMethod.DoInvoke (System.Object obj,
> System.Reflection.BindingFlags invokeAttr, System.Reflection.Binder
> binder, System.Object[] parameters, System.Globalization.CultureInfo
> culture) (at :0)
> System.Reflection.MonoCMethod.Invoke (System.Reflection.BindingFlags
> invokeAttr, System.Reflection.Binder binder, System.Object[]
> parameters, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture) (at
> :0)
> System.Reflection.ConstructorInfo.Invoke (System.Object[] parameters)
> (at :0)
> UnityEngine.Events.PersistentCall.GetObjectCall (UnityEngine.Object
> target, System.Reflection.MethodInfo method,
> UnityEngine.Events.ArgumentCache arguments) (at
> <4d9f7249f1de41e384668fea10e9822f>:0)
> UnityEngine.Events.PersistentCall.GetRuntimeCall
> (UnityEngine.Events.UnityEventBase theEvent) (at
> <4d9f7249f1de41e384668fea10e9822f>:0)
> UnityEngine.Events.PersistentCallGroup.Initialize
> (UnityEngine.Events.InvokableCallList invokableList,
> UnityEngine.Events.UnityEventBase unityEventBase) (at
> <4d9f7249f1de41e384668fea10e9822f>:0)
> UnityEngine.Events.UnityEventBase.RebuildPersistentCallsIfNeeded ()
> (at <4d9f7249f1de41e384668fea10e9822f>:0)
> UnityEngine.Events.UnityEventBase.PrepareInvoke () (at
> <4d9f7249f1de41e384668fea10e9822f>:0)
> UnityEngine.Events.UnityEvent.Invoke () (at
> <4d9f7249f1de41e384668fea10e9822f>:0) UnityEngine.UI.Button.Press ()
> (at C:/Program
> Files/Unity/Hub/Editor/2020.3.3f1/Editor/Data/Resources/PackageManager/BuiltInPackages/com.unity.ugui/Runtime/UI/Core/Button.cs:68)
> UnityEngine.UI.Button.OnPointerClick
> (UnityEngine.EventSystems.PointerEventData eventData) (at C:/Program
> Files/Unity/Hub/Editor/2020.3.3f1/Editor/Data/Resources/PackageManager/BuiltInPackages/com.unity.ugui/Runtime/UI/Core/Button.cs:110)
> UnityEngine.EventSystems.ExecuteEvents.Execute
> (UnityEngine.EventSystems.IPointerClickHandler handler,
> UnityEngine.EventSystems.BaseEventData eventData) (at C:/Program
> Files/Unity/Hub/Editor/2020.3.3f1/Editor/Data/Resources/PackageManager/BuiltInPackages/com.unity.ugui/Runtime/EventSystem/ExecuteEvents.cs:50)
> UnityEngine.EventSystems.ExecuteEvents.Execute[T]
> (UnityEngine.GameObject target, UnityEngine.EventSystems.BaseEventData
> eventData, UnityEngine.EventSystems.ExecuteEvents+EventFunction`1[T1]
> functor) (at C:/Program
> Files/Unity/Hub/Editor/2020.3.3f1/Editor/Data/Resources/PackageManager/BuiltInPackages/com.unity.ugui/Runtime/EventSystem/ExecuteEvents.cs:262)
> UnityEngine.EventSystems.EventSystem:Update() (at C:/Program
> Files/Unity/Hub/Editor/2020.3.3f1/Editor/Data/Resources/PackageManager/BuiltInPackages/com.unity.ugui/Runtime/EventSystem/EventSystem.cs:385)

Comment: Not sure but guessing that the underlying issue is actually that there is no `Transform` referenced at all. Unity's serializer will anyway generate an invalid "instance" of type `UnityEngine.Object` which will hold some additional error information (usually instead of a normal `NullReferenceException` you would get a `MissingReferenceException`) .. maybe this is an edgecase where due to the usage of reflection the casting goes south

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is referring to another section of code most likely. The error `cannot be converted to type` means that one type can not be implicitly converted to another type, in your case, `UnityEngine.Object` to `Transform`.

It is very hard to say exactly why this issue is happening from the two images you posted as they are of the hierarchy and are the exact same. If you add some code or add where the error is originating from, that would help. Similarly, posting any relevant code where you are trying to assign what you believe to be a `Transform` to an `Object`.

Comment: I added the full pic of the editor and I don't have any code connected to that button.

Comment: I believe it's because you had previously had the button onclick serialize a different object so it throws that error after the change.  Just assign a reference to the transform in your onclick